# Drag a file between Spaces while an Extended Display is connected

Tags: display, spaces

Is there a way to keep the ability to drag files from one Space to another while an external monitor is connected as an Extended Display?

I would like to drag a file from one Space to another.  Normally this is done by dragging the file to the edge of the screen and holding it there.  After a short time, the next Space moves into the screen and I can drop the file.  However, when there is an external monitor connected as an Extended Display, this functionality seems to be disabled.

Comment: What I usually do is select the file, press and hold the mouse, switch to the other space with Control-<Space number>, and then drop the file.

Comment: It should drag the Spaces across as you want it to. Personally I do it Jaume's way too, but dragging works, if slowly. Check System Prefs >Mission Control 'Displays have separate Spaces'. Is it on or off? It works if it's off, I can't test for if it's on. BTW, you do have to drag it fully to the right [or left] of *both* screens.

Answer (score 1):

Having **Displays have separate Spaces** checked apparently disables dragging items between Spaces within one display.<sup>*</sup>  However, I was able to work around as follows:

- Hold the mouse button down on the file to be moved.
- While holding the mouse button down, press the Spaces key (<kbd>F3</kbd> on my keyboard).  Available Spaces appear at the top of the screen.
- Drag the file to the desired Space.  Hold it there until the Space fills the screen.
- Drop file where desired.

<sup>*</sup> I see now that this behavior makes sense.  If you had a second display to the right of your main display, dragging a file to the right edge of the screen should either move it to the second display or to the next Space in the current display, but it's ambiguous which of those should happen.